# How to write pooling algoritm for lab work efficiency?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I was wondering if it makes sense to have a algorithm calculating the best combinations of samples to create pools in order to analyse each sample.

e.g.

I have 5 plant populations with different sizes

```
data = {'pop':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'size':[23,45,65,31,43]}
```

The goal is to analyse each plant for one gene.
What I could do it to analyse each plant individually, but that may involve too much labour.
Therefore, I was thinking in pooling populations in order to minimize the labour involved.

e.g. I could simply do pool1 = pop1,pop2,pop3 | pool2 = pop4,pop5
However, then I was thinking why not do pool1 = pop2,pop5, pool2 = pop1,pop3, and pool3 = pop4
So I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the optimal combination of populations or even plants (It is possible to split the populations in every desired way).

So when e.g. pool1 (pop1,pop2,pop3) is positive (desired gene found) then how to proceed in order to get to the individual plant that is positive, i.e. How to split the pool most effectively in order to get to identify the positive plants. It is likely that multiple plants of one population are positive

Overall I want to minimize the number of 'runs'

It is known that the expected frequency of positives is 0.036

I hope the idea is clear and somebody has ideas on how to do that

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the original partition of plants into populations is irrelevant. Is that correct?

Comment: For the analysis itself yes, I just introduced it to distinguish between plants better. Although it is likely that multiple plants are positive within a population. i.e. it is unlikely that only one plant of a certain population is positive.

Comment: Since the frequency of positives is very low, I think a simple dichotomy search should be enough?

Comment: I removed the `R` tag since I don't think this is an `R`-related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have N plants, and the frequency of positives is 0.036, then the total amount of information you get is -N(0.036 log<sub>2</sub> 0.036 + 0.964 log<sub>2</sub> 0.964) = 0.224N bits.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Ideally, since each run gives you a binary answer, you'll want to get a full bit out of each one, or at least as close to it as possible (and you'll therefore run just under N/4 runs in total).  You get a full bit when the probability of a positive result is 50%.  That takes 19 plants, so do your initial runs on batches of 19 plants.

After that, you'll probably get close enough to optimal by dividing each batch into halves and testing each half.

The initial batches require N/19 runs.

Then you have N/19 batches of size 10 to test.

You'll have N/16 batches of size 5 to test

N/15 of size 2.5.

For the N/30 positive batches of size 2.5, test each plant.

All together then, you have N(2/19+1/16+1/15+2.5/30) = 0.32N runs all together -- not too bad.

(note that @Stef's answer seems more efficient, but he got lucky in finding only 4 positives when 7 are expected :)

Let's try it:

```
import random

plants = [random.random() < 0.036 for _ in range(10000)]

nbuckets = len(plants)//19

buckets = [plants[i * len(plants)//nbuckets : (i+1) * len(plants)//nbuckets] for i in range(nbuckets)]

ntests = 0

def count_recursive(ar):
    global ntests
    if (len(ar)<=3):
        # run each plant
        ntests += len(ar)
        return ar.count(True)
    # run the batch
    ntests += 1
    if (ar.count(True) < 1):
        return 0
    mid = len(ar)//2
    return count_recursive(ar[:mid]) + count_recursive(ar[mid:])

print("Num plants: {}".format(len(plants)))
print("Num Positives: {}".format(plants.count(True)))
foundPositives = sum(count_recursive(b) for b in buckets)
print("Found positives: {} ".format(foundPositives))
print("Num tests: {}".format(ntests))
```

Results:

```
Num plants: 10000
Num Positives: 368
Found positives: 368
Num tests: 3310

Num plants: 10000
Num Positives: 325
Found positives: 325
Num tests: 3076

Num plants: 10000
Num Positives: 387
Found positives: 387
Num tests: 3526
```

Yup, as expected.

We can also do better by skipping a test when the result is guaranteed positive, because everything else in a positive batch tested negative.  That optimization brings to total number of tests down to 0.26N -- quite close to optimal.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your help! Matt, I really appreciate it! I guess the optimal number of test for 0.036 is 0.224N? I see that all positives are found. However, how you get to 19/16/15/30 is not clear for me. Also, I now a bit of python but the formula for bucket exceeds my knowledge, what is ":"? I know that 'buckets' forms the appropriate number of buckets. Also, the return of the function is not clear to me. Is there are way to show the intermediate bucket sizes? Thanks again and I hope to hear from you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the original partition of plants into populations is irrelevant to the question, I'll ignore it.

Since the frequency of positives is very low, I think a simply dichotomy search should be efficient. Occasionally, we will run into the situation that we split a positive pool into two subpools, and both subpools are positive, but since the frequency of positives is very low, we can hope that it won't happen too often.

```py
import random

# random data
n = 23+45+65+31+43
data = [{'id': random.random(),
         'positive':  random.choices([True, False], weights=[36, 1000-36])[0]
        } for _ in range(n)]

def test_pool(pool):              # tests if a pool is positive
  # serious science in the lab happens here
  return any(d['positive'] for d in pool)

def get_positives(data):
  result = []
  nb_tests = 0
  pools = [data]
  while pools:
    pool = pools.pop()
    if len(pool) == 1:
      result.append(pool[0])
    else:
      for subpool in [pool[:len(pool)//2], pool[len(pool)//2:]]:
        nb_tests += 1
        if test_pool(subpool):
          pools.append(subpool)
  return result, nb_tests

results, nb_tests = get_positives(data)
ground_truth = [d for d in data if d['positive']]

print('NUMBER OF TESTS: {}'.format(nb_tests))
print('FOUND POSITIVES:')
print([d['id'] for d in results])
print('GROUND TRUTH:')
print([d['id'] for d in ground_truth])
# NUMBER OF TESTS: 46
# FOUND POSITIVES:
# [0.2505629359502266, 0.46483641024238254, 0.8786751274491258, 0.250765592789725]
# GROUND TRUTH:
# [0.250765592789725, 0.8786751274491258, 0.46483641024238254, 0.2505629359502266]
```